# Select all text inside InputBox textbox

Tags: vb.net

How do I programmatically select all in vb.net InputBox?

```
 Dim ans As String
    Dim iznos As String = gridRacun.SelectedItem("kol")
    ans = InputBox("Enter value:", "Amount", 1111)
    If ans = "" Then
        ans = iznos
    ElseIf System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(ans, "[^0-9,-]+") Then
        ans = iznos
    ElseIf Convert.ToDouble(ans) <= 0 Then
        ans = iznos
    Else
        ans = ans
    End If
```

I want InputBox.textbox.selectall() so the user does not need to select all or delete all if he wants a value that is not already input.

Comment: You don't.  `InputBox` is a function, not an object, so trying to access amember of it is nonsensical.  Don't use `InputBox` at all, ever.  Create your own form and put a `TextBox` control on it and then you can treat that like a `TextBox`... because it is a `TextBox`.

Comment: So, why does InputBox selects everything if i call inputbox like this: `a = InputBox("Input value", "Delete number", 30)`

Comment: @stacks I guess who ever coded the implementation of Inputbox thought that if you have default value set (ie. 30) it would be easier for the user to change that if the text is already selected, hence you can just start typing the new value. But as for the question, do what jmcilhinney said.

Comment: If I run the code `InputBox("Enter value:", "Amount", 1111)` in a newly created form, the default text "1111" is selected. Doesn't that work for you? But honestly, `InputBox` is crap, better create your own form - the extra effort is minimal, and you have much better control over it.

Comment: Yeah, i guess it is way much better to make my own control. Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputBox` is a function, not a type.  When you call `InputBox`, the code that the function contains will create a form and add the appropriate controls and other functionality to it.  That includes a `TextBox` control.  If you create your own form with a `TextBox` on it and set the `Text` in the designer, when you display that form you will find that the text in the `TextBox` is selected by default.  That's exactly what happens with the form created by the `InputBox` method.

In your own form, you have access to the form itself and all the controls on it, so you can call `SelectAll` on the `TextBox` whenever you want.  When you call `InputBox`, you have no access to the form or its controls so you can't make it behave any way other than the author of that method intended.  Create your own form and you have full control over how it behaves and also how it looks.  It's rare that the `InputBox` function actually creates a UI that fits aesthetically with the rest of an application.